# Move uploaded function is not working

Tags: php

i try to upload image in my server , but image is not uploaded.

i face a problem in temp file ,

C:\Windows\Temp\phpE69F.tmp
how we upload the file in my server

MY Code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['Tmp_name'];
    if ($sourcePath) {
        $targetPath = "images/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
       if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)) {

           echo 'success';
       } else {

           echo 'fail';
       }

    } else {

        echo 'temp path not define';
    }

}
```

Comment: As in described in your title, that function is missing in your code.

Comment: no i try to upload . wait check this code   :                                                                      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['Tmp_name'];
    if ($sourcePath) {
        $targetPath = "images/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
       if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)) {
           
           echo 'success';
       } else {
           
           echo 'fail';
       }
       
    } else {
        
        echo 'temp path not define';
    }

}

Comment: Than please provide the code where you try to upload the image and not the check only. @AshishRana

Comment: If you are refereing w3schools, use the full code given at last part. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: The portion u gave is not complate

Comment: update your code into question not in comment

Comment: i updated my code , when i run this code , result is  (temp path not define)

Comment: change your `$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['Tmp_name'];` to `$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: i changed , but there is no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using the example from W3Schools, in your post you've only copied the check part, but at the end of the page you will see the full source.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Check it out!

Comment: my temp path is C:\Windows\Temp\phpE69F.tmp
     
how i can change this temp path, did you have any idea

Comment: Use overwrite it with PHP with the code `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your/path/here/'); ` or change the directory in your php.ini file.

Comment: sir , from where we get php.ini file

Comment: i have go daddy server , when i open server there is no file php.ini i found in my server

Comment: It's a shared hosting, I don't think they allow users to overwrite the php.ini file.

Comment: not possible for me to change in php.ini file ,Any other solution?

Comment: can i make my own php.ini file, is it possible

Comment: You should contact the Godaddy support to ask if you can edit or write your own php.ini file within their servers. I have no clue because I don't use shared hostings because all of these things.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['Tmp_name']; // <= WRONG index with uppercase should be ['tmp_name']
```

Comment: i changed , but there is no effect

Comment: actuallu  my temp path is   C:\Windows\Temp\phpE69F.tmp

Comment: how i can change temp path